# JNI: set jobjectArray from c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using the JNI for the first time.
I have this problem: in my java code there is an object that has an array of another object (defined by me) as field. Now, I need to set this object-array field from the native code. How can I do?

Thank you in advance! :)

Angela

---

My java code:

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyObject[] array; 
 ....
}
```

I need to set `array` from c++.

Comment: What does the constructor of `MyObject` look like?

Comment: Public MyObject(int ID) {this.ID=ID;}

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are passed a `JNIEnv *env` and a `MyClass` object from Java as `object` and that your classes are not in a package.

First we need to look up some classes and the constructor for `MyObject` objects:

```
jclass cls_MyClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");
jfieldID fld_MyClass_array = env->GetFieldID(cls_MyClass, "array", "[LMyObject;");

jclass cls_MyObject = env->FindClass("MyObject");
jmethodID ctr_MyObject = env->GetMethodID(cls_MyObject, "<init>", "(I)V");
```

Now we construct an array of size 10 and fill it with instances:

```
jobjectArray arr = env->NewObjectArray(10, cls_MyObject, nullptr);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  jobject elem = env->NewObject(cls_MyObject, ctr_MyObject, i);
  env->SetObjectArrayElement(arr, i, elem);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(elem); // Keep amount of local references constant
}
```

And we finally assign it to the `array` field:

```
env->SetObjectField(obj, fld_MyClass_array, arr);
```

Comment: It's just what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :)